# Where do I get the jar files for YUI Test code coverage?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automated-tests, yui

The [YUI Test -Code Coverage Utility documentation](https://github.com/yui/yuitest/wiki/Code-Coverage) suggests that we need some jar files to instrument the code:

```
yuitest-coverage-x.y.z.jar - used to instrument JavaScript code.
yuitest-coverage-report-x.y.z.jar - used to generate reports from the JSON code coverage output.
```

where do I get these jar files?  Please tell me there is a bin somewhere that I can download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build .jar files are available on GitHub, under https://github.com/yui/yuitest/tree/master/java/build